# Calculating outliers when values can't be below or above certain number

Tags: outliers

I have a dataset that for certain variables values can't be below or above certain number. For example Age, all values are and must be above 18. So when I try to calculate the outliers (I define Tukey's function myself), the function doesn't take this into account, and the outliers that come out don't make sense (it tells me that values for age below 14 are outliers).

I wonder if there is a way to solve this. Maybe a package that takes this into account?
I've thought about standardizing the variables. I hope I've explained myself well enough.

Thank you

Comment: If they are all supposed to be adults (18+) then any value below 18 it not an outlier, it is wrong.

Comment: Sure, then how do I calculate outliers in these variables? I'm thinking maybe it doesn't make sense to calculate the outliers, since values are restringed between two numbers.

Comment: One does not "calculate" outliers: one *determines* what might be an outlier based on some model, conception, or summary of the data.  If your conception is such that only anything under age 14 could be an outlier, then that's what it is.  The data very well could include values below 14 even though all values "must be above 18:" one of the points of screening for outliers is to find data that don't adhere to your criteria or expectations.